# How to Download file by url to exSdCard by using DownloadManager?

Tags: android, url, download

after this code it downloads to sdCard, but I need to download to exSdCard
I've tried to do it with

```
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title+".flv");
```

but not works... it downloads to internal memory

I also tried `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir (context,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title+".flv");`
but it downloads to internal memory **Android/data/com.example.app/files/Download** folder

in Samsung device: sdcard - it is internal
exSdCard it's http://content.answcdn.com/main/content/img/CDE/_COMPSD.JPG

```
 public void file_download(String uRl,String title) { 
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
+ "/Download/Videos"); 

if (!direct.exists()) { 
direct.mkdirs(); 
} 

DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE); 

Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl); 
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request( 
downloadUri); 

request .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI|DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE) 
.setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(title) 
.setDescription("/Download/Videos/"+title) 
.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, title+".flv"); 

mgr.enqueue(request); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getExternalStorageDirectory` is implemented to return whatever is set as "external storage" in the device environment.
It is not the removable media. Instead of that you just try to read the `isExternalStorageRemovable()` to check whether it is removable or not and also `getExternalStorageState()` to check the state. For more details http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: but how can I download to exSdCard by using DownloadManager?